# How to build Android SDK tools such as chimpchat or ddmlib?

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, compilation, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to compile some of the Jars from `<SDKROOT>/tools/lib` myself so I can make modifications and have javadoc+source jars. All the resources I can find reference either an old build system or want you to use `make sdk`, which does not compile JavaDoc or source jars.

Underneath `<SDKROOT>/tools/swt`, I'm only finding build.gradle files, most of which have dependencies that are not found. Can anyone advice on how I can build stuff inside the `tools` folder using `gradle`?

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.0_r1 -g all,-notdefault,tools
$ repo sync
$ cd tools/swt/chimpchat
$ gradle tasks
...
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'chimpchat'.
> No such property: archivesBaseName for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
$ cd ..
$ gradle tasks
...
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'swt'.
> Plugin with id 'sdk-files' not found.
$ cd ../base/ddmlib
$ gradle tasks
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ddmlib'.
> Plugin with id 'sdk-java-lib' not found.
```

There is a `<AOSP_ROOT>/tools/base` folder that does succeed at running `gradle tasks`, but it appears to have no subprojects or compilation-specific tasks defined.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar task to do - modify monkeyrunner.
I've given up and compiled sources using ANT as standalone application.
All reference libraries can find in AOSP (Nougat):

```
prebuilts/tools/linux-x86/swt/swt.jar
prebuilts/devtools/tools/lib/common.jar
prebuilts/devtools/tools/lib/ddmlib.jar
prebuilts/devtools/tools/lib/sdklib.jar
prebuilts/devtools/tools/lib/jsilver-1.0.0.jar
prebuilts/devtools/tools/lib/hierarchyviewer2lib.jar

and after: $ make guavalib
out/host/linux-x86/framework/guavalib.jar
```

My modification depends on chimpchat.jar which have also be modified, hopefully sources are in tools folder too, so same way: ANT->compile and build jar.